# CarouselView not showing the data

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel

I am trying to display a CarouselView inside a TabbedPage. I already added the (prerelease-)packages to the Project. Here is my xaml file:

```
            <control:CarouselView x:Name="CVMain"
                                  HeightRequest="150" >
                <control:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <Label HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   Text="Just a test :)"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </control:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </control:CarouselView>
```

(control: `xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"`)

The label doesn't show up when I launch my app. The carousel still exists tho, I can confirm that by adding the `BackgroundColor="Green"`attribute to the `CarouselView`.

What am I missing?

Edit: As suggested, I placed the `Label` inside a `Grid`, but without any success (I also added an Image):

```
        <control:CarouselView x:Name="CVMain" HeightRequest="150">
            <control:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"
                               Aspect="AspectFill"
                               Source="{Binding ImageBase64,
                                                Converter={StaticResource Base64ToImageConverter}}" />
                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
                            <Label Text="Test123" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </control:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </control:CarouselView>
```

Comment: Could you try wrapping the `Label` in a `Grid` as per [this example](https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/)

Comment: No success.. Tried a few variants to place it inside the grid, but it doesn't have any influence.. I'm gonna update my question with the grid-variant in a few secs^^

Comment: Note that the `Label` in the example has `FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"` just to make sure there isn't some quirk in there

Comment: Tried that too, but even the image isn't showing up :/

Comment: Managed to get it working just by downgrading to  version 2.3.0-pre1 (from pre2). But after I a while, the app crashed with this exception: "CarouselView Crashes with "Sequence Does not Contain a Matching Element'". This bug was fixed in version 2.3.0-pre2 xD

Comment: So, what is the solution? both pre-1 and pre-2 don't work?

Comment: I did this: Downgrade to pre-1, reinstalled Xamarin.Forms, clean, rebuild. After that I upgraded to pre-2 again and everything worked. Weird solution, but it worked out for me :)