# Image Slider CarouselView problems in Xamarin Forms (IOS)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I have read most of the questions posted here like this [CarouselView not showing the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636537/carouselview-not-showing-the-data) and [Xamarin Form: Carousel View not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607007/xamarin-form-carousel-view-not-showing)  on CarouselView but still me i get no luck, i am doing this common **monkey example** https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/  but when i run on the simulator  i see nothing, when i give it a background color  it shows it .I even tried  a simple example to populate list of numbers in a CarouselView but still it wasn't displaying anything.What is exactly the problem?

This was my expectation , but still no luck :

1. Is it the pre-release of **Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView** which has the problem or because i see it has two versions i have to choose one ?  (But i tried each of them but still no luck)
2. Am i supposed to use CarouselView.FormsPlugin instead of the Above if so what clear protocol should i take to achieve this ?

**My XAML**

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height=".3*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height=".7*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <cv:CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Zoos}" x:Name="CarouselZoos">
    <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
          <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="#80000000" Padding="12">
            <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
          </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
  </cv:CarouselView>
  <!--List of Monkeys below-->
</Grid>

My C#
```

**Model Class**
public class Zoo

```
{
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
public class MonkeysViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Monkey> Monkeys { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, Monkey>> MonkeysGrouped { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Zoo> Zoos { get; set; }

    public MonkeysViewModel()
    {

        Monkeys = MonkeyHelper.Monkeys;
        MonkeysGrouped = MonkeyHelper.MonkeysGrouped;
        Zoos = new ObservableCollection<Zoo>
        {
            new Zoo
            {
                ImageUrl = "http://content.screencast.com/users/JamesMontemagno/folders/Jing/media/23c1dd13-333a-459e-9e23-c3784e7cb434/2016-06-02_1049.png",
                Name = "Woodland Park Zoo"
            },
                new Zoo
            {
                ImageUrl =    "http://content.screencast.com/users/JamesMontemagno/folders/Jing/media/6b60d27e-c1ec-4fe6-bebe-7386d545bb62/2016-06-02_1051.png",
                Name = "Cleveland Zoo"
                },
            new Zoo
            {
                ImageUrl = "http://content.screencast.com/users/JamesMontemagno/folders/Jing/media/e8179889-8189-4acb-bac5-812611199a03/2016-06-02_1053.png",
                Name = "Phoenix Zoo"
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code/ github repo to demonstrate what you have tried.

Comment: check those links in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok , me too i had the same problem but this is how i solved mine but i don't know why.

**STEP 1:**

Check the **Packages** Folder under your **projectname** , right click on it and click **add package** , then search *Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView* then install it (version *2.3.0 pre 1*).

**STEP 2:**

Check also under **projectname.IOS** and **projectname.DROID** the  **Packages** Folder, also right click on it and click **add package** , then search *Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView* then install it (version *2.3.0 pre 1*).

**NOTE:**

Install the same version Don't forget this.

Then run the App and see the output , hope it helps :-)

**Happy Coding**